# What's the best approach for adding tags to post in multilanguage site?

Tags: php, web, tags, multilingual

Sorry for my English.

I want to add multilanguage tag to my website. Everything is ok. In below i add picture please look at this. But my method is not good.

First problem is Forexample "php" tag is same in every language. If tag is "student" this is different for other languages. Forexample in Turkish its "öğrenci". So if i want to count the php tags in posts i must use extra sql queries.

Second problem is in below i have 3 db tables. In adminstration tag fields i add error if not same amount of tag in each field because in tagslang table same tag_id for every language for one post. If i add 3 tag to one language but add 2 tag to other languages others last column is become empty.

Third problem is if url in site like "en/articles/tag/student" if i switch language url to turkish "tr/articles/tag/student" this is problem because there's no tag in turkish like student. But 2 tags have same tag_id. So if i change url "en/articles/tag/student" to "tr/articles/tag/ogrenci" this is also problem because maybe in other posts student tag has different turkish translation other than "ogrenci". So i must use limit 1.

db table tag has -> tag_id

db table taglangs has -> id,tag_id,language,name

db table tagassign has -> class(means Post model class), post_id, tag_id

Maybe some other problems. But i think adding tag to post in multilanguage site is different than my method.

[Adminstration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LDRMu.jpg)

Comment: Maybe make it so there is only one set of tags that can be displayed in different languages rather than a different set of tags for every language.

Comment: how about this. news tag for english, novosti for russian, haberler for turkish. This is translation of news for other languages. How can i do it in one set o tag?

Comment: Have a table that contains tags with a translation for each language then associate rows in that table with whatever you are tagging.

Comment: And also maybe in some post same tag name have different translation in other post. Because some english word has multiple translation in russian depends on post text.

Comment: That's still possible with a tags table. When picking a tag you just have to show all the translations for each one so that the correct one is picked.

Comment: i tell you my method clearly.
If i add tags to adminstration tags field like this
En - news,student
Ru - новости,студент

In db tagslang table like this.
tag_id=1,language=en,name=news
tag_id=1,language=ru,name=новости
tag_id=2,language=en,name=student
tag_id=2,language=ru,name=студент

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommeded to use multi keywords for every language. You should never write your backends based on each lang. Onr approach (not best) for multilang is to use file config for each language. Its like dictionary. Then in each file config you just store variable that holds word in that language. Suppose you have en and fr. Then create file like lang.php

```
$student = array( 'en' => '...', 'fr' => '...' );
```

For your ui you can use this method. Now for youe queries just use the name in english. Set every thing in english and retrive data from db in english. Then for example one of your tag name was student so you in file lang.php you have student variable witch you can access to its turkish by:

```
${*student*}['tr']
```

Now you have your tag in turkish.

Comment: i use yii2 framework. The standart and basic method for language system. Problem is not  this. I must use multi keywords in project. if someone add multiple tags to english so it must have translation in other languages. If its international word i must add same tag for other languages.

Comment: I see. So how do you translate them when someone add some tags? Manually??

Comment: And also where do you store translations?

Comment: lang.php advice is good but what i know which user add which tag? how can i translate all of them. But if give initiative to user add tag this is easy for me

Comment: Its not easy to translate all tags. You can use services like google translate to translate each tag then save the tags in lang.php or more easy save it in json and store it in db then in each startup load the json file and then read tags in deferent labguage from that.

Comment: Google translate not useful. It is not convert all tags correctly. So my priority is adding all tags with translation to db. User must enter from adminstration.

Comment: The point is saving tags translation in db is not recommended ( of course in sql language db ). You can at least save words in json form then store it in db. But if your approach works steak on it. :D

Comment: It works.There's problems which developers know. Normal site user's unaware about this problems. But i think someone has effective method to adding to db. Some sites uses tag system for multilanguage which i searched but they use subdomains for each language. They language db is different.